# Umbraco 4.6. Can not create file in Media Section. "No Document exists with Version "

Tags: umbraco

I listed out the installed packages I have just in case I installed something that would cause this conflict but everything else is unaltered.

[image]
 [image]

When I go to create a file or folder in the media section, I get the following error:

At /umbraco/webservices/TreeDataService.ashx?rnd=2ff1d740390747b1bb041eac478be535&id=-1&treeType=media&contextMenu=true&isDialog=false&rnd2=14.4 (Referred by: http://umbraco/umbraco/umbraco.aspx):

Then when I go to that URL, I get

No Document exists with Version 'blah blah blah'

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Wow.. 57 installed packages?! So ehm.. after installing which package did Umbraco stop working? Try to isolate the packages that work with the media section. Also, try to get a better error message, either from the umbracoLog table or the windows event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm this is strange. I've seen this bug before:

http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/29032

http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/29258

It's a bug if you try to add the TinyMCE editor to the media type, but it should have been fixed in Umbraco 4.6.1.

Not sure if this info helps...